# Initialize a matrix with constant string in c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to initialize this matrix with a constant string (i.e. "@"), in order to fill it later. Hence, the output is not what I'm expecting. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Can you give me some advice on how to better initialize the matrix with a constant string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
char* Board[3][3];
char* PLAYER = "X";
char* COMPUTER = "O";

void displayBoard() {
    printf(" %c | %c | %c ", Board[0][0], Board[0][1], Board[0][2]);
    printf("\n---|---|---\n", Board[0][0], Board[0][1], Board[0][2]);
    printf(" %c | %c | %c ", Board[1][0], Board[1][1], Board[1][2]);
    printf("\n---|---|---\n", Board[0][0], Board[0][1], Board[0][2]);
    printf(" %c | %c | %c ", Board[2][0], Board[2][1], Board[2][2]);
    printf("\n---|---|---\n", Board[0][0], Board[0][1], Board[0][2]);
}

void FillBoard() {
    char* initialValue = "@";
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            Board[i][j] = initialValue;
        }
    }
}

int main () {
    FillBoard();
    displayBoard();
}
```

Output:

```
 f | f | f
---|---|---
 f | f | f
---|---|---
 f | f | f
---|---|---
```

Comment: "I'm trying to learn c++ by doing some easy stuff that I find on the internet." A big mistake. Don't. Get yourself a good book.

Comment: @Pietro Amin Puddu You need to use the conversion specifier %s instead of %c in the calls of printf.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, and actually use C++.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Of course, actually I'm reading a guide of Herbert Schildt. But, doing some stuff, sometimes, forces you to learn something that you did not absorbed by just reading the book.

Comment: @PietroAminPuddu Schildt has been legendarily awful for over twenty years. Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many isssues. Explanation in comments.

But as one of the a comments above says: get a good C++ book. BTW your code is rather C code than C++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
char Board[3][3];
const char PLAYER = 'X';    // you don't need a pointer here, you need a char here
const char COMPUTER = 'O';  // same as above

void displayBoard() {
  printf(" %c | %c | %c ", Board[0][0], Board[0][1], Board[0][2]);
  printf("\n---|---|---\n");   // removed the extra arguments
  printf(" %c | %c | %c ", Board[1][0], Board[1][1], Board[1][2]);
  printf("\n---|---|---\n");   // removed the extra arguments
  printf(" %c | %c | %c ", Board[2][0], Board[2][1], Board[2][2]);
  printf("\n---|---|---\n");   // removed the extra arguments
}

void FillBoard() {
  const char initialValue = '@';  // you don't need a pointer here, you need a char here
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      Board[i][j] = initialValue;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  FillBoard();
  displayBoard();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For one, you have made a critical mistake in your above code example. Don't ever write(in C++ atleast):

```
char* initialValue = "@";    //incorrect
```

Instead the correct way to write the above statement is:

```
const char* initialValue = "@";    //correct
```

This is because the use of string literal without the `const` keyword is forbidden. See [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/O7tGeLLPeSMbq6Vu)

Also you could just use/create a matrix of `char` instead of `char*` as you did in your example and similarly for other uses of `char*`. Jabberwocky 's answer shows this.

Comment: This is just _one_ problem.

Comment: Why not just `char `? There’s no reason for it to be a string and even less reason for it to be a C-string.